# Deploying models to web service in private network on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

When my Azure Machine Learning workspace is configured in private network and isolated from puclic network, what happens when deploying models to web service?

I understand that online(real time) endpoint and batch endpoint inherit workspace's network configuration but can't find any official Microsoft documents.

Is the deployment to web-service also same?

real time endpoint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-secure-online-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-studio
batch endpoint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-batch-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2

references

real time endpoint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-secure-online-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-studio
batch endpoint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-batch-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe when you deploy to a web service, it provides 2 options for compute type:

1. **AksCompute**
2. **Azure Container Instance**

[image]

Here, you need to configure your private network settings. When you try to create **AksCompute**, it asks for the **Kubernetes Service** which you need to configure for a [secure Kubernetes inferencing environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-kubernetes-inferencing-environment?view=azureml-api-2).

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-inferencing-vnet?view=azureml-api-2) documentation which explains two inference options that can be secured using a VNet:

1. Azure Machine Learning managed online endpoints
2. Azure Kubernetes Service

You can refer to using Azure Kubernetes Service, which will be used in web service deployment.